# declaring serviceintent in androidmanifest

Tags: java, android

I have a class which extends serviceintent called bluepostservice.  In another class in the same package which extends activity i call

```
Intent selectIntent = new Intent(this, bluepostservice.class);
this.startService(selectIntent);
```

I have this in my manifestxml

```
<service android:name="BluePostService" />
```

However i get

Unable to start service Intent { cmp=org.anddev.android.parsingxml/.BluePostService }: not found

Clearly I've declared something wrong in the manifest or started the service improperly.

How do you properly declare a service intent in the androidmanifest?

Answer (score 0):

Missing the dot?

```
<service android:name=".BluePostService" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check did you declare the service inside the application tag.

```
 <application> 
.................
..............
<service android:name="BluePostService" />  
................
..................
</application>
```

Edited:
what do you mean by serviceintent?You should declare like that

```
 public class BluePostService extends Service {

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

Then from your Activity

```
Intent selectIntent = new Intent(this, BluePostService.class);
this.startService(selectIntent);
```

May be your problem is you have declared that service in manifest like `"BluePostService"` but you want to start it like `"bluepostservice"`. So may be its the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it shoud be like this:

```
<service android:name="bluepostservice" />
```

> The android:name attribute is the only required attribute—it
>   specifies the class name of the service.

Answer (score -1):

you need to enable this service by using attribute:

```
 service android:enabled="true" android:name=".your service name">
```